# classification of bugs ownership by their content (improve score for log analysis)

Tags: machine-learning, python, nlp, scikit-learn, text-classification

I'm doing a little project in which given a dataset of bugs and their relevant owner, I'd like to predict the "final owner" of a non-analyzed bug (bugs tends to assign back and forth between different owners and I'm referring to the "real/final owner" as the final one based on the dataset).

Number of classes/labels is 6

The data I use to make these decisions relays mostly on the bug's content which can be a subset of the following:

- Error logs
- Python tracebacks
- Panics
- Panics traces

I'm also using `SMOTETomek` to balanced the dataset (it creates artificial training data) - this alone increased my results by 10-15%.

However, I'm still getting a very low score (around 65%) when applying a set of classifiers (Each is being trained against the above mentioned data)

Example for classifiers I've tried: SGDClassifier, MultinomialNB, BernoulliNB, LinearSVC, RandomForestClassifier, LogisticRegression, DecisionTreeClassifier, ExtraTreeClassifier, etc.

My pipeline looks as follows:

```
def train(self, algorithm, X_train, y_train):
    model = Pipeline([
        ('vect', CountVectorizer()),
        ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
        ('smote', SMOTETomek()),
        ('classifier', algorithm)
    ])
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    return model
```

where each algorithm in the pipeline is one of the above mentioned classifiers (it's being run in a loop for each one)

Initially I thought that the root cause for this fairly low score is the way I'm sanitize the data.

For example: For errors, I'm relaying on regex to clean timestamps, thread ID, etc. For python tracebacks I'm getting rid of line numbers and taking just func names

Later on I was surprised to find out that even without cleaning the data, I'm getting the same score, so it made me think I'm missing something

My features are simply text I cleaned from the logs and (each feature is just a long string) and the labels are (each) simply a number that correlates to a class.

How can it be that no matter what I do (cleaning the logs vs leave it untouched) faces me with the same score? Am I using the wrong steps in the pipeline? missing steps?

Any help will be appreciated as I've no clue where/how to proceed.

Comment: Before creating a pipeline, looking at the raw table of data, do you think you could figure out what the labels are by looking at the input data?  Think about how you can break down (ie generate features) that make sense to you of how you may classify a bug. Also it helps to see a sample of the data to determine the quality of the input.

Comment: @fswings Am I wrong or do I only have 1 final feature (since we're talking about text analysis)?
Each feature I have is actually a long string of different items I thought will be relevant to feed the classifiers with

Comment: So 'features' here are in effect the input columns. Having a single feature won't help models distinguish between the observations. What you need to do is take the input data and create columns or features that can help a model distinguish between bugs. It's much easier to assist if you share a sample of the data here.

Comment: @fswings Assuming each row I'm using looks like that `{'A': 'strA', 'B': 'strB', 'C': 'strC', 'label': 'some label'}`.
Do I need to unite all features to a single value (e.g `{'features': 'strA strB strC', 'label' 'some label'}`)?

Comment: No Ben, having individual columns is the right approach. Given the type of discussion we're having I get the impression you're just starting your ML journey. If so, I would recommend this book: https://github.com/amueller/introduction_to_ml_with_python as a great starting place to cover the key principles.

Comment: I've read the book multiple times, the first time I'd suggest without looking at the code and just try and absorb the key principles.